# SerialPort.ReadExisting Method not displaying received data

Tags: c#, exception, methods, serial-port, grasshopper

The following code is building without errors but when I run the program, the received data does not show in the output. When I place a breakpoint on the `myReceivedLines = port.ReadExisting();` I get:

`System.InvalidOperationException`.

In the program itself, after restarting my computer it says:

`Access to COM5 is denied`

What can I do to fix this?

Code:

```
//Fields
SerialPort port;
string myReceivedLines;

   protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
  {

    List<string> gcode = new List<string>();
    DA.GetDataList(0, gcode);
    string selectedportname = default(string);
    DA.GetData(1, ref selectedportname);
    int selectedbaudrate = default(int);
    DA.GetData(2, ref selectedbaudrate);
    bool connecttodevice=default(bool);
    DA.GetData(3, ref connecttodevice);
    bool sendtoprint= default(bool);
    DA.GetData(4, ref sendtoprint);


    if (!DA.GetDataList(0, gcode)) return;
    if (!DA.GetData(1, ref selectedportname)) return;
    if (!DA.GetData(2, ref selectedbaudrate)) return;
    if (!DA.GetData(3, ref connecttodevice)) return;
    if (!DA.GetData(4, ref sendtoprint)) return;


    port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); //Create the serial port
    port.DtrEnable = true;   //enables the Data Terminal Ready (DTR) signal during serial communication (Handshaking)
    port.Open();             //Open the port
    port.DataReceived += this.portdatareceived;


    if (gcode == null)
    {
        AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "Specify a valid GCode");
        return;
    }

    if (connecttodevice == true)
    {
        DA.SetDataList(0, myReceivedLines);
    }

        if (sendtoprint == true)
        {
            foreach (String s in gcode)
            {
                port.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }

              }


    //subscriber method for the port.DataReceived Event
    private void portdatareceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            myReceivedLines = port.ReadExisting();
    }
```

Comment: This may not be the cause of your problem, but you are attaching your DataReceived Event **After** You Open your port. In my mind that should be done right after you new up the SerialPort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SerialPort's DataReceived Event operates on a different thread than the UI thread. You will need to do something like the MSDN Page for The [DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Event suggests. The reason why you get the access denied error is because the port is still open, reboot your computer to correct restarting your program is not enough.

i.e. from above link

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler( object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
}
```